# Failed to get a Wordpress JSON

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I have a problem with a JSON that I recover from a site with WordPress, the problem is that when I try to consult the JSON, my query does not return anything.

I tried using Alamofire to recover my JSON but it does not work either, I do not know how to recover the JSON that returns my site with WordPress

I have tried to recover the JSON in the following way but it does not work, it does not return anything:

let urlString = URL(string: "https://www.sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&tags=(id)")

```
    let request = URLRequest(url: urlString!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else{
            print("Solicitud fallida \(error!)")
            return
        }

        do{
            print("Recibimos respuesta")

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: String]{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let titulo = json["rendered"]
                    let content = json["content"]
                    let excerpt = json["excerpt"]

                    print(json)
                    print(titulo!)
                    print(content!)
                    print(excerpt!)
                }
            }
        }catch let parseError {
            print("Error al parsear: \(parseError)")
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("respuesta: \(responseString!)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

I have also tried with Alamofire in the following way:

Alamofire.request("https://www.sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&tags=(id)").responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

```
        if let json = response.result.value as? JSON{
            print(json)
        }

    })
```

But it still does not work.

This is the structure that JSON has:

[   {
    "id": 3438,
    "date": "2019-04-01T06:02:50",
    "date_gmt": "2019-04-01T12:02:50",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/?p=3438"
    },
    "modified": "2019-04-01T06:02:50",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-04-01T12:02:50",
    "slug": "documento-2019",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/documento-2019 /",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Documento 2019"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/document.pdf \" class=\"pdfemb-viewer\" style=\"\" data-width=\"max\" data-height=\"max\" data-mobile-width=\"500\"  data-scrollbar=\"none\" data-download=\"off\" data-tracking=\"on\" data-newwindow=\"on\" data-pagetextbox=\"off\" data-scrolltotop=\"off\" data-startzoom=\"100\" data-startfpzoom=\"100\" data-toolbar=\"bottom\" data-toolbar-fixed=\"off\">document.pdf 
\n",
      "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "closed",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [
      39
    ],
    "tags": [
      54,
      55
    ],
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3438"
        }
      ],
     "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
        }
      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
        }
      ],
      "replies": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=3438"
        }
      ],
      "version-history": [
        {
          "count": 1,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3438/revisions"
        }
      ],
      "predecessor-version": [
        {
          "id": 3440,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3438/revisions/3440"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=3438"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "category",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=3438"
        },
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=3438"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }   }]

The console does not return any errors on the JSON

[image]

Comment: The result is `[[String: Any]]` note the square brackets `[]`, and `Any` because the values are at least `Int`, `String` and `Dictionary`

Comment: Yes, you're right, now what I do not understand is how I can recover the data from some label that comes in the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type is `[[String: Any]]`.

`if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]`

To get the URL for the author, drill down into the JSON like this:

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
    if let links = json[0]["links"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        if let author = links[0]["author"]? as? [String: Any] {
            if let authorURL = author["href"] as? String {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works to recover my JSON but now I do not understand how to get the values ​​of the tags that are in the JSON, I mean how to recover this:

author = ({href = "some link"})

Comment: `, options: .allowFragments)` is meaningless here

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa  this also should work , what is the problem

Comment: @Sh_Khan This block of code gives me error in: , options: nil, the error is: "Nil is not compatible with expected argument typ 'JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions '"

Comment: Oh, try `[]` instead of `nil`

Comment: @COSMOBAKER If I remove the options: nil, it gives me this other error: Can not subscribe to value of type [[String: Any]] with an index of type String on this line: if let author = links["author"]?[0]

Comment: Updated @EnriqueEspinosa

Comment: @COSMOBAKER I have updated my question with an image of the errors I have

Comment: Updated @EnriqueEspinosa